# How to fix the problem with lists in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I write a python program for **Port Scanning**

***here my source code is...***

```
import socket

t_host = str(input("Enter the host to be scanned: "))  

t_ip = socket.gethostbyname(t_host) 

print(t_ip)   

list=[1,3,4,6,7,9,13,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,32,33,37,42,43,49,53,70,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,88,89,90,99,100,106,109,110,111,113,119,125,135,139,143,144,146,161,163,179,199,211,212,222,254,255,256,259,264,280,301,306,311,340,366,389,40]

sock = socket.socket()  

sock.settimeout(1)

for item in list:
    t_port=int(item)
    result = sock.connect_ex((t_ip,t_port)) 
    if result == 0:
        print("Port",t_port,": Opened")
    else:
        print("port",t_port,": Closed")
    sock.close()

print("Port Scanning complete")
```

when I'm using single item in list it scans and give the port opened/closed correctly.(i.e) First item in list is evaluated correctly wheras remaining is not evaluated as open or closed correctly

eg. `list=[80]` it gives output as open correctly.

But if the list contains more than one items it gives Closed for all ports

eg. `list=[80,23,443,25]` it gives output as `port 80 : Opened`  but remaining are closed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check your formatting in your question and ensure that all code is marked as code with the `{}` button

Comment: Found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486561/how-can-i-reconnect-a-socket-after-a-broken-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to the list of ports, 
but a socket object you are using multiple times.

Once a socket is closed, [it can not be reused](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close):

> Mark the socket closed. The underlying system resource (e.g. a file descriptor) is also closed when all file objects from makefile() are closed. Once that happens, all future operations on the socket object will fail. The remote end will receive no more data (after queued data is flushed).

You'll probably want to create a new socket for each scanned port:

```
import socket

t_host = str(input("Enter the host to be scanned: "))
t_ip = socket.gethostbyname(t_host)

print(t_ip)
list=[1,3,4,6,7,9,13,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,32,33,37,42,43,49,53,70,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,88,89,90,99,100,106,109,110,111,113,119,125,135,139,143,144,146,161,163,179,199,211,212,222,254,255,256,259,264,280,301,306,311,340,366,389,40]

for item in list:
    t_port=int(item)

    # create a new socket for each port scanned
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.settimeout(1)

    # probe port
    result = sock.connect_ex((t_ip,t_port))
    if result == 0:
        print("Port",t_port,": Opened")
    else:
        print("port",t_port,": Closed")
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reuse the same socket for multiple connections. You need to create a new socket each time through the loop.

```
for item in list:
    t_port=int(item)
    sock = socket.socket()  
    sock.settimeout(1)
    result = sock.connect_ex((t_ip,t_port)) 
    if result == 0:
        print("Port",t_port,": Opened")
    else:
        print("port",t_port,": Closed")
    sock.close()
```

From the documentation of [`socket.close()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close):

> All future operations on the socket object will fail.

Comment: Proposal: add reference to Python document: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close

Comment: @Cychih Added, with a copy of the appropriate sentence.